# Setter and getter using angular service/factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass big chunk of data from controller A to controller B.

so I made this factory

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .factory('holdCustomCover', function($scope, img_data) {
        return {
            save: $scope.img_data = img_data;

            get: $scope.img_data;
        }
  })
```

am I doing it right? so later in controller A what should I do? like
`holdCustomCover.save(myImgDataHere)`?

Then in controller B I do `holdCustomCover.get()` I can get the img value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't inject `$scope` inside `factory`/`service` funciton. Service/Factory are singleton object which are responsible for data sharing. You should have common code over there only.

In your code you have to create a function for getter & setter, which will return `img_data` which is private data for `holdCustomer` factory.

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .factory('holdCustomCover', function() {
      var img_data; //private data
        return {
            //setter
            save: function (data){
              img_data = data;
            },
            //getter
            get: function(){
              return img_data;
            }
        }
 })
```

Comment: why `get` need to be a function? can't it be just `get: img_data`?

Comment: @JennyMok no, with the way assignments are done. It will only consider the initial value(`undefined`), again it depends how you did all the bindings.. Better have functino and return variable each time. Though if you do that.. It wouldn't have been called as getter at all..

Comment: I see. So what is the best practice here? how people usually do it? I assume I need a service/factory to share data, I don't know what should be done right actually.

Comment: @JennyMok getter and setters are totallly fine, look at the code how I modified it.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help Pankaj! I'm new to angular :D